# Unchecked cast в generic методе

Tags: java, generics, dao

Я хочу сделать универсальную фабрику для DAO-классов, чтобы при добавлении не приходилось писать новый метод "getNewEntityDao". Мне подсказали как правильно в данном случае использовать дженерики. И теперь это выглядит как-то так…

```
package com.employees.dao.impl;

import com.employees.dao.*;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class JDBCDaoFactoryImpl implements DaoFactory {

    private Map<Class, GenericDao> daoMap;
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(JDBCDaoFactoryImpl.class);

    public JDBCDaoFactoryImpl() {
        daoMap = new HashMap<>();
        daoMap.put(CountryDao.class, CountryDaoImpl.getInstance());
        logger.info("Added dao for " + CountryDao.class.getSimpleName());

        ...

        daoMap.put(ParkingSpaceDao.class, ParkingSpaceDaoImpl.getInstance());
        logger.info("Added dao for " + ParkingSpaceDao.class.getSimpleName());
    }

    @Override
    public <T extends GenericDao> T getDao(Class<T> entityClass) {
        logger.info("Get dao for " + entityClass);
        if (!daoMap.containsKey(entityClass)) {
            logger.warn("Dao object for " + entityClass + " not found.");
            return null; //Maybe throwing exception be better
        }
        return (T)daoMap.get(entityClass);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JDBCDaoFactoryImpl factory = new JDBCDaoFactoryImpl();
        CarDao dao = factory.getDao(CarDao.class);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(dao.getClass().getSimpleName());
    }

}
```

Но у меня возникло несколько вопросов: во-первых, в строке возврата из метода висит "Unchecked cast", и я никак не могу убрать этот warning (аннотация `SuppressWarnings` не в счет). А во-вторых, я не совсем понимаю чем является `Т` при вызове метода, к примеру как в `main`, при вызове с `CountryDao.class` чему равен `Т` в этом случаее.

Comment: Приведите заголовки классов/интерфейсов, которые используете (CountryDao, CountryDaoImpl, CarDao, CarDaoImpl...)

Comment: А это не слишком расходует ресурсы? Ведь в случае отдельных методов типа `getNewEntityDao` экземпляры соответствующих `DAO` будут создаваться по требованию, а в вашем примере они все сразу создаются. А если их много? Сотни таблиц, представляющих собой `Entities` это вполне себе норм для Enterprise...

Comment: @Vadim нашел способ избавиться от "Unchecked cast"?

Comment: @golubtsoff Да я вообще не эксперт по Java. Конечно, нет.

Comment: @Vadim, сейчас задал аналогичный вопрос. Посоветовали сделать как-то так: `return (T)daoMap.get(entityClass);` заменить на `entityClass.cast(daoMap.get(entityClass));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Так как у вас в Map хранятся GenericDao в качестве значений без преобразования не обойтись. Компилятор не может знать какой там тип и предупреждает, что могут быть ошибки преобразования.
2. Т -это как параметр. Вы описываете общее поведение метода - получает параметр типа Class и возвращает значение типа T. T равен CarDao. Если "подставить" фактический тип вместо параметра, то получится:

   ```
   public CarDao getDao(Class<CarDao> entityClass)
   ```

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю за что переживает компилятор, за то что в Map будет лежать то, что не удастся привести к переданному типу, или что будет передан такой тип, что к нему не удастся привести то что в Map? И почему в данном случае ограничения(extends) наложенные на тип не помогают?

Comment: Да. Что не удасться привести. Вы можете положить `CarDao`, а потом попытаться привести к `CountryDao`. Оба этих класс будут наследниками `GenericDao`, но из разных веток. Поэтому ограничение не даст необходимой информации.